# SQLHANDLE-Parameters: function does not take x arguments (but it does, actually)

Tags: c++, parameters, reference

I implemented some function in c++ to handle sql-queries and stuff. Because I am doing this in different functions using the same handles, I am giving the handles as parameters (actually I want to inout references to the handles - but I am new to c++ and still having trouble understanding the concepts behind pointers and so).

Because the Error-Message is saying, that there is no function with x parameters, but there actually is one (there is a forward declaration as well), I think, that the definition and the use I am trying to make of it are somehow wrong.

Here is the forward declaration:

```
static HRESULT 
_OpenDatabase(
    LPCWSTR connectionString, 
    SQLHANDLE hdlStmt, 
    SQLHANDLE hdlEnv, 
    SQLHANDLE hdlConn
);
```

And the call (getting the connection string as input: __in LPCWSTR ConnectString)

```
SQLHANDLE hdlStmt = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
SQLHANDLE hdlEnv = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
SQLHANDLE hdlConn = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    hr = _OpenDatabase(
        ConnectString,
        &hdlStmt, // this might be wrong?
        &hdlEnv, // and this
        &hdlConn // and this
    );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're putting `&` in front of the arguments. Why? You have 3 `SQLHANDLE`, you need 3 `SQLHANDLE`.

Comment: I want to use the handles outside of the _OpenDatabase()-function. I thought, I would get a reference to the objects created inside the function this way, don't I?

Comment: @stl: No, that gets you a pointer. A `SQLHANDLE*` to be precise.